# Select highest value in row with microsoft access sql

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

So my table format is as follows:

```
Project | type1 | type2 | type3 | type4  
a | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2  
b | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1  
c | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0
```

I need the max of each row, as follows:

```
Project | max  
a | 2  
b | 1  
c | 0
```

I cannot use the switch() function in access because I have too many variables and it gives the "too complex" error. any ideas?

`SELECT Switch(`
`[MaxOfBudget Trigger] = 2, "Critical",`
`[MaxOfSchedule Trigger] = 2, "Critical",`
`[MaxOfSubmittals Trigger] = 2, "Critical",`
`[MaxOfSafety Trigger] = 2, "Critical",`
`[MaxOfChange Orders Trigger] = 2, "Critical",`
`[MaxOfContingency Trigger] = 2, "Critical",`
`[MaxOfRFIs Trigger] = 2, "Critical",`
`[MaxOfBudget Trigger] = 1, "At Risk",`
`[MaxOfSchedule Trigger] = 1, "At Risk",`
`[MaxOfSubmittals Trigger] = 1, "At Risk",`
`[MaxOfSafety Trigger] = 1, "At Risk",`
`[MaxOfChange Orders Trigger] = 1, "At Risk",`
`[MaxOfContingency Trigger] = 1, "At Risk",`
`[MaxOfRFIs Trigger] = 1, "At Risk",`
`[MaxOfBudget Trigger] = 0, "Okay",`
`[MaxOfSchedule Trigger] = 0, "Okay",`
`[MaxOfSubmittals Trigger] = 0, "Okay",`
`[MaxOfSafety Trigger] = 0, "Okay",`
`[MaxOfChange Orders Trigger] = 0, "Okay",`
`[MaxOfContingency Trigger] = 0, "Okay",`
`[MaxOfRFIs Trigger] = 0, "Okay",      )`
`AS test, [Project Triggers].[Project Number]`
`FROM [Project Triggers];`

Comment: you should normalize the table design, which would make this a relatively trivial query...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database isn't normalized the way it should be.
You should have a `type` table, with the values 1,2,3,4 in it, and then a join table to your `project` table.

```
|project | type_id | value |
+--------+---------+-------+
|a       | 1       | 0     |
|a       | 2       | 1     |
|a       | 3       | 1     |
|a       | 4       | 2     |
|b       | 1       | 1     |
|b       | 2       | 0     |
|b       | 3       | 1     |
|b       | 4       | 1     |
|c       | 1       | 0     |
|c       | 2       | 0     |
|c       | 3       | 0     |
|c       | 4       | 0     |
```

Then you can do something like `SELECT project, max(value) FROM project_type_values GROUP BY project;` to get your results.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it's a tad more complicated but I figured it out. I have ~7 or so tables, and I was creating calculated fields for each table (each calculation is different) but the solution to the calculation is 1 of 3 possible types (good bad or risk). I ended up keeping the same structure, but writing a union all query to create the proper format (like you suggested)

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with Daniël's answer, and I hope you are able to modify the data model. But if you can't, you might declare a function that can return the largest of a list of numbers:

```
Function MaxOfList(ParamArray varValues()) As Variant
    Dim i As Integer        'Loop controller.
    Dim varMax As Variant   'Largest value found so far.

    varMax = Null           'Initialize to null

    For i = LBound(varValues) To UBound(varValues)
      If varMax >= varValues(i) Then
        'do nothing
      Else
        varMax = varValues(i)
      End If
    Next

    MaxOfList = varMax
End Function
```

A slightly more advanced version, as well as its `Min` counterpart can be found at 
[Allen Browne's Access Tips: MinOfList() and MaxOfList() functions](http://allenbrowne.com/func-09.html)

Comment: not quite the solution i was looking for, but this is very useful VBA so thanks Golez, i could def use this in the future :)